# How can I see what my friends are playing on Xbox One without the console?

Tags: xbox-network, xbox-one

My friends on Xbox Live always come up as "Online playing Xbox One" when I see them on the Xbox Live website or on my Windows Phone.  If I get on my Xbox One I can see what game they are playing, but through any other means then the actual console I cannot see what my friends are actually doing on their Xbox One.

Any ideas on how to see what my friends are up to without booting the actual console?

Comment: I believe since they are different "live" platforms thats a technical limitation right now. Since I don't know for sure this isn't an answer.

Comment: At this time its not possible to know what your friends are playing on the Xbox One on the `Xbox 360`.  The same isn't true on the Xbox One, your friends, can see what your playing on the `Xbox 360`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, other than booting up the console, [Xbox Smartglass](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/smartglass) (available on most mobile platforms, and Windows 8) is currently the only way to see what they're playing.